# Crash upon delete through destructor

Tags: c++, strcpy

In the following program, i intend to copy `char* line` contents from one object to another through `strcpy`.
However when the program ends, destructor of `obj2` works fine but dtor of `obj` crashes. gdb shows different addresses of `line` for both objects.

```
class MyClass {
        public:
                char *line;
                MyClass() {
                        line = 0;
                }
                MyClass(const char *s) {
                        line = new char[strlen(s)+1];
                        strcpy(line, s);
                }
                ~MyClass() {
                        delete[] line;
                        line = 0;
                }
                MyClass &operator=(const MyClass &other) {
                        delete[] line;
                        line = new char[other.len()+1];
                        strcpy(line, other.line);
                        return *this;
                }
                int len(void) const {return strlen(line);}
};

int main() {
        MyClass obj("obj");
        MyClass obj2 = obj;
```

Comment: Even though you use C-style null-terminated strings you're still programming in C++.

Comment: You need a copy constructor too. [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Comment: That is because i was asked to simulate copy string in c++ through strcpy

Comment: Just as an aside, once you add a copy constructor: `MyClass obj1; MyClass obj2 = obj1;` will still segfault because you will call `strlen(obj1.line)` which is `strlen(NULL)`. As would `MyClass obj1; obj1.len();`.

Comment: Also undefined behavior: `MyClass obj1;  obj1.len();`  It is undefined behavior to call `strlen` on a null pointer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With

```
MyClass obj2 = obj;
```

you don't have assignment, you have ***copy-construction***. And you don't follow the [rules of three, five or zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) since you don't have a copy-constructor, so the default-generated one will just copy the pointer.

That means after this you have two object whose `line` pointer are both pointing to the exact same memory. That will lead to *undefined behavior* once one of the objects is destructed as it leaves the other with an invalid pointer.

The naive solution is to add a copy-constructor which does a deep-copy of the string itself, similarly to what your assignment operator is doing.

A better solution would be to use `std::string` instead for your strings, and follow the rule of zero.

Answer (score 5):

You need create a copy constructor. This has to do the [rule of 3/5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three/4172724#4172724). You are creating `obj2`, which means a copy constructor is invoked, not the copy assignment operator.

Because you don't have a copy constructor, a "shallow" copy is made. This means that `line` is copied by value. Since it's a pointer, both `obj` and `obj2` are pointing to the same memory. The first destructor gets called and erases that memory just fine. The second constructor gets called and a double delete occurs, causing your segmentation fault.

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
  char *line = nullptr;
  std::size_t size_ = 0;  // Need to know the size at all times, can't 
                          // rely on null character existing
  const std::size_t MAX_SIZE = 256;  // Arbitrarily chosen value
  MyClass() { }
  MyClass(const char *s) : size_(strlen(s)) {
    if (size_ > MAX_SIZE) size_ = MAX_SIZE;
    line = new char[size_];
    strncpy(line, s, size_ - 1);  // 'n' versions are better
    line[size_ - 1] = '\0';
  }
  MyClass(const MyClass& other) : size_(other.size_) {  // Copy constructor
    line = new char[size_ + 1];
    strncpy(line, other.line, size_);
    line[size_] = '\0';
  }
  ~MyClass() {
    delete[] line;
    line = nullptr;
  }
  MyClass& operator=(const MyClass &other) {
    if (line == other.line) return *this;  // Self-assignment guard
    size_ = other.size_;
    delete[] line;
    line = new char[other.size_ + 1];
    strncpy(line, other.line, size_);
    line[size_] = '\0';
    return *this;
  }
  int len(void) const { return size_; }
};
```

When dealing with C-Strings, you absolutely cannot lose the null character. The issue is that it's extremely easy to lose. You were also lacking a self-assignment guard in your copy assignment operator. That could have led to you accidentally nuking an object. I added a `size_` member and used `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()` because being able to specify a maximum number of characters is incredibly important in the case of losing a null character. It won't prevent damage, but it will mitigate it.

There's some other stuff that I did like using [Default Member Initialization](https://abseil.io/tips/61)(as of C++11) and using a constructor [member initialization list](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/8-5a-constructor-member-initializer-lists/). A lot of this becomes unnecessary if you are able to use `std::string`. C++ can be "C with classes" but it's worth taking the time to really explore what the language has to offer.

Something that a working copy constructor and destructor allows us to do is simplify our copy assignment operator using the "copy and swap idiom."

```cpp
#include <utility>

MyClass& operator=(MyClass tmp) { // Copy by value now
  std::swap(*this, tmp);
  return *this;
}
```

[Link to explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom/3279616#3279616).

Comment: A better solution would be an implementation using copy and swap idiom.

Comment: Learned a new thing, and I like it. I'll add an extra bit.

Comment: Thanks for copy using swap example